# Deploy to remote server using scp in NANT script

Tags: nant, scp

I am trying to copy a file to a remote server using scp task in Nant.Contrib .

I have used the following code to do that:

```
<target name= "QADeploy"description="gthtyb" >
<loadtasks assembly="C:\nantcontrib-0.85\bin\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />
<echo message="htyh"/>
<scp file="D:\SourceTest\redist.txt" server="\\10.4.30.19" user="xxx:uuuu">      
</scp>
</target>
```

But I am getting an error: scp failed to start. The system cannot find the file specified.
The code is as follows:
Then I have downloaded pscp.exe and modified the code as below:

```
<target name= "QADeploy"
    description="gthtyb" >
 <loadtasks assembly="C:\nantcontrib-0.85\bin\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />

<echo message="htyh"/>

<scp file="D:\SourceTest\redist.txt" server="\\10.4.30.19" user="xxx:uuuu" program="C:\pscp\pscp.exe">      
</scp>
```

Now I am getting the following error:

[scp] ssh_init:host does not exist

External Program Failed:C:\pscp\pscp.exe

can u please help whats the best way to copy a file to a remote server using Nant. I am using this code to deploy files to a remote server.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work locally? on a server? anywhere? is the server accessable vis SCP from the command line?

Comment: how can I check if a server is accessible via scp?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put two backslashes behind the IP of your server.

```
<scp file="D:\SourceTest\redist.txt" server="10.4.30.19" user="xxx:uuuu" program="C:\pscp\pscp.exe">
```

Also note that without the "path" parameter, the default destination folder is "~".

**Update**: it is the username that is crashing the pscp.exe program. Remove the ":" from your username or try with a different one.

Comment: Can you try by using "/" for your program path ?
Or set the "program-path-sep" parameter to "\" ?

Comment: Can you also launch with the "-v+" option to turn debug output ?
Can you also try to launch pcsp on the command line ?

Comment: when I tried to launch pscp and copy the file using command line I am getting the error: ssh_init:host does not exist

Comment: Is there any other way of transferring files to remote server in Nant script. Any help will be highly appreciated. Why is scp not working directly from Nant.contrib.Tasks.dll

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there is some weirdness on how pscp parses paths in windows. The following should fix ssh_init:host does not exist problem:

```
-upload
pscp some.file user@[remote-host-or-ip]:/some/path/

-download
pscp user@[remote-host-or-ip]:/some/path/some.file  some.file
```